# Timeout errors, what to do about 503?

Tags: php, http-status-code-503

I'm connecting to a web service using SOAP in PHP. Everything was working fine when using Xampp on my computer but when I moved the PHP code to a web server, my timeout problems started.

First I got a timeout after 30 secs. max_execution_time fixed that.
Then I got a timeout after 60 secs, default socket timeout fixed that.

Now I get a 503 error after exactly 5 minutes. I am not sure how to fix that. I know the reason is simply that I am getting a lot of data and the fact that it is always exactly 5 minutes (+1 to 2 secs) means that it is a timeout.

But what can I do about it? Do I need a third time extender?

**Edit**

I also got the 503 error when this was my only code:

```
<?php
echo "hello"; 
sleep(305);
?>
```

So I assume there must be a timeout for something that I don't know about. But I have no idea how to check for those timeouts or if I can actually change those.

Comment: Somewhere I read that I could get some helpful information by reading the error logs on the server. But for some reason, I can't see any error information with my timestamp.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Hackerman No, that's a bit difficult. It's a lot of code. Most of it was generated using wsdltophp.com. But I don't think the code itself is the problem, it works when I am not getting so much data. I just need a way to tell the server to wait a bit longer before giving me an error.

Comment: Which webserver and how is PHP being used? Fcgi, fpm, etc?

Comment: @mkaatman Look at my update. Even that simple code gives me an error. Apache

Comment: and I don't even know what fcgi and fpm are

Comment: sleep is misleading as it doesn't apply to all timeouts. Unfortunately, you've got an environmental problem that is going to be difficult to diagnose. Take a look at this: http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks. I'm on a shared server so I am not able to try the Apache timeout directive. Maybe that's the problem. I've tried every other timeout option on the list

Comment: It probably is, they don't want people running scripts that run that long most likely.